# CI project error in upload image to 000webhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

Hello I did project with codeigniter and uploaded it to 000webhost.it worked but the image no.

```
.button_signup{
    background:url('http://localhost/helloworld/images/signup.png ' ) no-repeat;
    height:40px;
    width:100px;
    border:0;
}

 <?php $id = 1; ?>
 <form action="<?php echo base_url('log_c/signup/' . $id); ?>" method="post" >
```

this code to get image submit it worked at localhost But doesn't appear in website.how can i edit to work in website? please
and this my config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

Comment: When you change the hosting you have to change all non-relative links like "http://localhost/helloworld/images/signup.png" in your example. You also have to set a base_url (e.g. $config['base_url'] = 'http://mywebsite.com';

Comment: you mean $config['base_url'] = 'mysql6.000webhost.com';  this myhost

Comment: how to edit 'http://localhost/helloworld/images/signup.png '

Comment: you have to set your external url (http://mywebsite.com). I think mysql6.000webhost.com is just an internal url.

Comment: I set url external   $config['base_url'] = 'www.areegadel.comli.com';  but get error404webhost

Comment: Also tried with http:// and removed the www? The models and controller have also to begin with a capitalletter (e.g. Welcome.php insteat of welcome.php). Your header-tag has also <img width="1080" height="90" src="http://localhost/helloworld/images/header.jpg "> instead of <img width="1080" height="90" src="<?php base_url(); ?>"/images/header.jpg ">

Comment: it works..... thanks very much